# Betting game with numbers

Tags: probability, gambling

Someone is challenged to play the following game: there are 36 marbles in an urn. 21 of them are red, 9 are blue and 6 are green. Each red is worth 0 rupees, each blue 100 rupees and each green 1000 rupees. By betting 1000 rupees only once, you must pick as many marbles as you want (obviously without seeing its color), one by one (you draw each marble, look at its color and either stop or continue) and without replacement and you can stop at any time, and you earn the product of the values of the marbles you have picked so far.

Assuming that the player plays optimally, what is the average percentage of the average percentage of profit for the game?

My understanding is that we must calculate the probability (not) to draw a 0 in a series of consecutive draws from 1 to 36.

For the 1st draw, the probability to get a 0 is $P_1 = \frac {21}{36}$ and the game ends, so with probability $P'_1 = \frac {15}{36}$ the player continues ("optimal" playing refers to this, otherwise if he continues, he will get 0 anyway).
Up to now, the player has earned 100 rupees with probability $Pw'_1 = \frac {15*9}{36*15}$ and 1000 rupees with probability $Pww'_1 = \frac {15*6}{36*15}$.
For the 2nd draw, the probability not to get a 0 is $P'_2 = \frac {14}{35}$ and so on.
The player will earn again the product of either 100 or 1000 of the first earning, with probability equal to the product of $P'_2$ by $\frac {8}{14}$ or $\frac {5}{14}$.

Can you please help me continue? It is getting really confusing from this point forward!

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question requires some clarification. The answer posted seems correct to me, and it's not clear whether you disagree with it because it misinterprets the question or because you don't understand it. To me, "you can stop at any time, and you earn the product of the values of the marbles you have picked so far" sounds as if you only get a payout once, when you stop. But later you write "The player will earn again the product of either $100$ or $1000$ of the first earning". Does that mean that you get a payout after every draw, even if you then continue drawing?

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is at least one blue or green marble in the urn, it makes sense to keep playing, since you have a better than 1 in 36 chance of multiplying your winnings by at least 100. So the optimal strategy is to draw 15 marbles. Your expected earnings will be the product of: (1) the probability that every one of the first 15 marbles drawn is non-red, times (2) the number of rupees you will earn if you draw all 15 non-red marbles and no red marbles. Can you compute these two quantities? The result is kind of funny, in that you wind up with a minuscule probability of winning an astronomically large amount of money.

**Edit**: There are
$$
{36\choose 15}=\frac{36!}{15!\, 21!}=5567902560
$$
possible sets of 15 marbles you could draw. Exactly one of them has no red marbles, so using the optimal strategy, the probability you win money is $1/5567902560$. In the event you draw 15 non-red marbles, the amount of money you win is $100^9\cdot 1000^6 = 10^{36}$. Your expected winnings are then
$$
\frac{10^{36}}{5567902560}\approx 1.796\cdot 10^{26},
$$
and your expected percent profit is
$$
\frac{\frac{10^{36}}{5567902560}-1000}{1000}\cdot 100\%\approx 17960084416419816082413526\%.
$$

Comment: Julian, thank you for your answer. Just to clarify: You don't draw all the marbles at once, but one by one: You see them first and then decide if you will continue and so on. Obviously if you draw a zero, you must stop, because whatever you draw afterwards, you will earn the product, which will be zero.

Comment: Well, once you draw a red marble, it doesn't matter what you do, so you don't *have* to stop. My argument is that whatever happens on the draws, it is optimal always to continue drawing until you have drawn 15 marbles.

Comment: I did some calculations with Excel and got an average of ~22% - does this seem reasonable?

Comment: I got an expected profit much larger than that

Comment: Can you please share some calculations? I am not sure my method is correct. Thank you.

Comment: This is not optimal playing. According to the OP, you must play optimally. Plus, this is an one-off case. You must get the average earning of all possible cases.

Comment: To me, optimal playing means you continue drawing as long as you don't get a red and until you get a green. Of course, after this, you can continue playing, to maximise your earnings. In all other cases, you are losing money. Therefore, this is what you need to calculate.

Comment: Hmm, I do not understand the comments here. If there is objection to continuing to draw after a red marble, the player could continue to draw until you getting a red or reaching 15 marbles, which has the same payout as always drawing 15 marbles. I interpret "optimal strategy" to mean one that maximizes expected payout. Using the strategy I propose, the player earns 0 rupees with probability $5567902559/5567902560$, and earns $10^{36}$ rupees with probability $1/5567902560$. Did I make a mistake in this calculation? Or is there a strategy with higher expected payout?

Comment: The question is not about the optimal strategy or the highest payout, but about the average payout, based on all possible outcomes. Maybe I haven't explained it correctly. If you get a red on any draw, there is no point to continue. Whatever you get after this point, it doesn't matter, because you will get 0 anyway! So let's say, for example, you want to spend 100.000 rp (in total): You start with your first "game": You bet 1000 rp, you draw a red, and you stop. Then you bet another 1000, you draw a blue, then a green and you continue. To secure your earning so far, you stop, and start a new.

Comment: I think I am still missing something. The average payout depends on what strategy you use. The strategy I propose have an average payout of $\approx 1.8\cdot 10^{26}$, and I am claiming that no strategy does better.

Comment: Are you saying you play multiple games without replacing the marbles between games?